# Is it possible to loop a method with different parameters?

Tags: java, loops, methods, compare

so this is the case.

I'm doing an excercise where I have to compare each random number with all my static numbers from an external file `lotto.dat`

I have to make a method `doCompare()` which returns either true or false. My question will appear after my code:

```
public static void drawNumbers()throws Exception{

  Random rnd = new Random();

  int rndN1 = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;
  int rndN2 = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;
  int rndN3 = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;
  int rndN4 = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;
  int rndN5 = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;
  int rndN6 = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Winner numbers: " + rndN1 + " " + rndN2 + " " + rndN3 + " " + rndN4 + " " + rndN5 + " " + rndN6);

  String match = doCompare(rndN1);

  if(match.equals("true")){

     System.out.println("Match on the number: " + rndN1);

  }
}
```

So is it possible somehow loop the "doCompare" with parameters "doCompare(rndN1)" then rndN2, rndN3 and so on or what else should I do to make this work?

Comment: But how do I, the second time the loop goes through change the parametr to rndN2 instead of 1?

Comment: Learn about collections, this is too broad to be a question here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a List which can collect your integers. Create a loop which create the integers and add them to a list. While creating the random integers, you can create the output string in the loop too. And at the end use another loop for the method call `doComapre()` and pealse change the return value of `doCompare()` method to `boolean`. Then you can use it in the if statement and have not to check if the return value is equals `"true"`.

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<Integer> rndNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    String outputString = "Winner numbers:";

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        rndNumbers.add(rnd.nextInt(19) + 1);
        outputString = outputString + " " + rndNumbers.get(i);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(outputString);

    for(Integer curNumb : rndNumbers)
    {
        String match = doCompare(curNumb );

        if (match.equals("true"))
        {
            System.out.println("Match on the number: " + curNumb );
        }
    }
```

Maybee you can use an array because you are always want to generate six numbers. And for the String creation you can replace the String with a Stringbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper data structure, like an array or a `List` to store the random numbers and loop over them:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int cout = 0 ; count < 6 ; ++count) {
    numbers.add(rnd.nextInt(19)+1);
}
// ...
for(int n : numbers) {      // go through all the numbers in the list
    doCompare(n); 
}
```

Comment: Should probably replace the Array with a Set, to skip duplicates (as probably this is a lottery drawing app he is writing)

Comment: I am not sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create array or list and store rnd number and then loop over it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but not as you want to do it.

you have to create a list of your rndNX values

Like so:

```
List<Integer> rndList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

fill it like so :

```
rndList.add(rnd.nextInt(19)+1);
rndList.add(rnd.nextInt(19)+1);
...
```

And use the list :

```
for(final Integer rndI : rndList)
{
    String match = doCompare(rndI );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new Random();

  System.out.println();

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  int rndN = rnd.nextInt(19)+1;

  String match = doCompare(rndN);

  if(match.equals("true")){

     System.out.println("Match on the number: " + rndN1);

  }
}
```

You could do something like this.  Instead of initializing all your random numbers first initialize them in a loop as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Store the int values into the array or a list and loop through it.